# $\int_{a}^{\frac{a+b}{2}}\frac{g(x)}{(1-x)^2}dx\geq\int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^{b}\frac{g(x)}{(1-x)^2}dx$?

Tags: integration, functions, interval-arithmetic

Suppose $g>0$, $g$ decreasing on $[a,b]$ where $0<a<b<1$. Is it true or false that
$$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{\frac{a+b}{2}}\frac{g(x)}{(1-x)^2}dx\geq\int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^{b}\frac{g(x)}{(1-x)^2}dx ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the following stronger Lemma which is easy to prove:

> *Lemma*:I Let $f$ be an strictly increasing function. Then
>   $$\int_{a}^{a+L}f(x)\, dx<\int_{b}^{b+L}f(x)\, dx \forall L>0\iff a<b$$

Now the main point is to see that we can apply this lemma in your case as both intervals share the same length. You just need to chose $g$ such that $\frac{g}{(1-x)^2}$ is strictly increasing: for example $g=1$ or $g=1-x$

Comment: Ok it's clear but, How prove this in general?

Comment: I have given you a clear counterexample, which thus makes sure that the statement cannot in general be true. On the other hand, you can examples where the claim does hold true, so no conclusion can be made a priori.\

Comment: Suppose that $g(x)=(1-x)^3$,$a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Then $$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{5}{8}}(1-x)dx=\frac{7}{128}>\frac{5}{128}=\int_{\frac{5}{8}}^{\frac{3}{4}}(1-x)dx$$. So this is not a counterexample

Comment: I've added a more general (correct) solution

Answer (score 0):

The inequality does not hold. Counterexample: $g(x)=1$ and $0 \lt a=\frac{1}{4} \lt b=\frac{3}{4} \lt 1$ then:

$$\int_{1/4}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{1-x} \bigg|_{1/4}^{1/2} = \;\frac{2}{3} \quad \lt \quad 2\; = \frac{1}{1-x} \bigg|_{1/2}^{3/4}  = \int_{1/2}^{3/4}\frac{dx}{(1-x)^2}$$